# FileField/ImageFIeld URL isn't giving me a HTTP URL

Tags: django, django-templates

I have this code, where partner.logo is an ImageField in the Partner model.

```
{% for m in matches %}
<img src="{{ m.partner.logo }}" alt="" />
<h2><a href="{{ m.partner.url }}">{{ m.partner.name }}</a></h2>
<p>{{ m.reasons }}</p>
<p>{{ m.partner.profile }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Now, the Django documentation says if you go m.partner.logo.url, you'll get a URL to the file. However, all I got was

```
<img src="/Users/shinichi/Dropbox/source/blastoise/uploads/road-sky-clouds-cloudy.jpg" alt="" />
```

and that actually is the same string that I'd get from m.partner.logo. This isn't a URL, and it's not helping! I was expecting something like http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/road-sky-clouds-cloudy.jpg. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you confirm that you have your `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` properly set in your settings?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some problems with the `MEDIA_URL` and the `MEDIA_ROOT` on the `settings.py` (please take a look [here](https://github.com/vladir/django-image-example/blob/master/django_image_field/settings.py#L30)) as pointed by @domino. I've written an example to you [here](https://github.com/vladir/django-image-example). There is one important detail too when referencing the logo URL, you probably will need to do something like [this](https://github.com/vladir/django-image-example/blob/master/main/templates/index.html). I mean:

`{% for partner in partners %}
        <img src="{{ partner.logo.url }}" alt="" />
        <h2><a href="{{ partner.logo.url }}">{{ partner.logo }}</a></h2>
    {% endfor %}`

Remember to add [these](https://github.com/vladir/django-image-example/blob/master/django_image_field/urls.py#L28) lines on your `urls.py` to help you with serving the `media` resources on development, it always helps a bit with.

Hope that it can help you mate.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you've set your `MEDIA_ROOT` to in proj/settings.py file. In your models.py file, you can designate the `upload_to` argument in the `FileField`. Here's the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#filefield) on that.

You can designate other places. The most popular is [Amazon S3](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html). I set my template to read

`<a href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/fsbo-facebook/{{ house.photo }}" data-lightbox="{{ house.title }}" data-title="{{ house.title }}"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/fsbo-facebook/{{ house.photo }}" alt="{{ house.title }}"></a>`

Hope this helps.